# SQL Server - Get record where not exist on other table

Tags: sql-server, select

I have two tables:

[image]

[image]

I want to get result in Campaign table - > **55,100**.

Because they don't exist in `Jobs` table.

Comment: Which `DBMS`, What have you tried so far, where you got stuck?

Comment: I made a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uh58R1LSZFBMhjC12zULmK/0) for this with the first answer as they test.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `not exists` condition:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   campaign c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   jobs j
                   WHERE  j.campaignid = c.campaignid)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this:

```
select * from campaign
 where 1 = 1
   and campaignid is not null
   and campaignid not in (select campaignid from jobs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #Campaign (CampaignId int NULL)
create table #Jobs (JobId int, CampaignId int)

insert into #Campaign values (1),(2),(3),(4),(100),(55)
insert into #Jobs values (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,1),(6,3),(7,3)

select distinct C.CampaignId
from #Campaign as C
where not exists(select 1 from #Jobs as J where C.CampaignId = J.CampaignId)
```

Result is
55
100

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN where the id is null:

```
SELECT c.* from campaign c
LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs j ON j.CampaignId = c.CampaignId
WHERE j.CampaignId IS NULL;
```